# Check if Document class has empty pageContent in python from json file and delete empty contents

Tags: python, json, document, langchain

I am using langchain's Document to read in a json file line by line using the following code but the resulting output has a few elements with blank pagecontent (https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/schema/document)
How do I count how many have empty pagecontents?

```
import json
from  langchain.schema import Document
from typing import Iterable

def load_docs_from_jsonl(file_path)->Iterable[Document]:
    array = []
    with open(file_path, 'r') as jsonl_file:
        for line in jsonl_file:
            data = json.loads(line)
            obj = Document(**data)
            array.append(obj)
    return array
```